# Strange NOT IN operator behavior

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE something IN (a, b, c)
```

produces normal results, and,

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE something NOT IN (a, b, c)
```

should give me all results from column *something* in table *somewhere*, but it gives me many times more randomly repeating lines than there is in a table. All examples of NOT IN on the internet are with strings of text, and I'm working with numbers, is there something different?

Comment: Are your `select` statements really that simple, or are you joining several tables?

Comment: No way. There must be something wrong with your data. **IN/NOT IN** operations should behave as you described.

Comment: Also, there are no special rules for using `not in()` with numbers, it behaves exactly as expected. Please update the question to include your actual queries, because as it stands your question isn't answerable - `in/not in` simply do not behave the way you're describing.

Comment: Can you include your real schema and query and some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiving "many times more" rows in your result is almost always the result of an improper join.  Examine the JOIN statements in your FROM clause and/or any table relationships you specify in you WHERE clause.

Make sure that you aren't including any tables in your FROM clause that aren't properly joined to the other tables in the SELECT statement.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, how can I test if there is no improper joins, when postgresql doesnt give me any errors and the IN test returns me right results.

Answer (score 4):

Without the "real" queries, it's hard to say what's going on...

Tat said, and adding to Michael's answer, make sure you don't have null values in the `not in` clauses, as the semantics are then quite different from those with the seemingly opposite `in` clause:

```
select a from b where a in (1, null);     -- rows where a = 1
select a from b where a not in (1, null); -- no rows, since x <> null is null
```

Comment: null neither matches not does't match a value - ie any test (other than `is null`) is always false. if just one of the values in the list is null, comparisons will always be false